# Simulate and test a keypress event with Mocha, Chai, Sinon?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a Backbone view that has custom events for `keyup` and `keydown` events.

```
events: {
    "keyup .search-box": "changeTextTimer",
    "keydown .search-box": "cancelTextTimer"
},
```

I'm writing unit tests to check if those callbacks are getting invoked after a keyup or keydown. I use jQuery to trigger the key event.

```
it("should call cancelTextTimer", function() {
    var searchBox = new SearchBoxView({el: $(HTML),}).render();

    var e = $.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 65;
    searchBox.$(".search-box").trigger(e);

    var changeTextTimer = sinon.spy(searchBox, "cancelTextTimer");
    _.defer(changeTextTimer.restore);

    changeTextTimer.should.have.been.calledOnce;

});
```

However, I receive a

```
AssertionError: expected cancelTextTimer to have been called exactly once, but 
it was called 0 times: Got value cancelTextTimer but expected a value undefined undefined
```

Comment: You're setting up your spy after you've triggered the click, what happens when you move it to the second line in your test function?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson that's answer material.

Comment: @HenrikAnderson Hmm it still gives me the same error

Comment: Does `searchBox.$(".search-box")` find elements? I noticed you are passing in the HTML (`el: $(HTML)`) - that might be a possible source of error

Comment: @mikeapr4 It does find the element. In my view class I append `.search-box` to the $el. I pass $(HTML) as the el, and in my test I have a variable called HTML that has an empty div. I'm not sure if it is needed but either way I get the same error.

Comment: So I use put some console.log to make sure that my tests to make sure the callbacks are getting called when I simulate the keypress/keydown/keyup. They are getting invoked, but my tests don't recognize this, and still say my callbacks are called 0 times

Comment: @bceltics93 it is not needed to pass an empty `div` to a view as Backbone creates one by default.

Comment: @bceltics93 if you paste the actual view code as well, it might be easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
it("should call cancelTextTimer", function(done) {
    var searchBox = new SearchBoxView({el: $(HTML),}).render();
    var changeTextTimer = sinon.spy(searchBox, "cancelTextTimer");
    _.defer(changeTextTimer.restore);

    var e = $.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 65;
    searchBox.$(".search-box").trigger(e);

    setTimeout(() => {
        changeTextTimer.should.have.been.calledOnce;
        done();
    }, 0);

});
```